# "Unable to find template" with Docker

Tags: docker, symfony, configuration, twig, symfony5

I created a Symfony environment with Docker. I then included this file in my web project (skeleton website). But when I try to access my *base.html.twig* page located in a main folder from the controller, I get this error:

> Unable to find template "main/base.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/templates, /var/www/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).

How can I solve the problem? I have version 5 of Symfony.

Here is the content of my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    php:
        container_name: "php-fpm"
        build:
            context: ./php
        environment:
            - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
            - APP_SECRET=${APP_SECRET}
        volumes:
            - ${APP_FOLDER}:/var/www
        networks:
            - dev

    nginx:
        container_name: "nginx"
        build:
            context: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - ${APP_FOLDER}:/var/www
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx/
        depends_on:
            - php
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - dev

    db:
        image: mysql
        container_name: "db"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        networks:
            - dev

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: "phpmyadmin"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
        networks:
            - dev


networks:
     dev:
volumes:
     db-data:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) file needs to link local folders with Docker folders.

```
#docker-compose example

version: "3"
services:

 web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www # Map local folder to Docker
```